# How to list most viewed recent videos?

Tags: youtube

I would like to get the list of most viewed recent videos on YouTube without specify a tag or a keyword. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [YouTube Charts](http://www.youtube.com/charts).

This gives the most viewed videos by

- Today
- This week
- This month
- All time